# OpenGL glViewport and glScale

Tags: opengl

Is it ok to call glViewport (and glScale) multiple times per frame (maybe about 10 times) or are there any reasons to avoid that?
That would make things like e.g.GUIs much easier for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly fine to do this, and actually the way to go for things like GUIs.

However you should avoid glScale. Not for performance reasons, but because it's part of the fixed function pipeline matrix functionality. …which has been deprecated and removed entirely from modern versions of OpenGL. Better use something like GLM and update uniforms, or use glLoadMatrix if you really want to use fixed function.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i'm not sure what GLM is or what you mean with fixed functions (i'm not working long wiht openGl for now...)

Comment: i'm using glLoadIdentity and glOrtho (2d game) now, is that ok?

Comment: @slukas96 datenwolf meant that you are using fixed-function pipeline (was in use before GL 3), instead of modern shader-based approach (GL 3 and 4). You will need to google up and probably pick some modern OpenGL 3 or OpenGL 4 book. Please, let fixed function stuff already die.

Comment: @slukas96: Just to make this clear: The programmable pipeline has been around since OpenGL-2 (i.e. almost 10 years). OpenGL-3 did away with all the old, cumbersome cruft. Things like the whole old fashioned matrix stack may look appalling at first, but they're a burden on the long run, because it makes people make poor design decisions.